Lenovo Integrated Pen not detected by Lenovo Thinkpad X13 Yoga G4 running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I recently received from my employer a Lenovo Thinkpad X13 Yoga Gen 4 (type 21F2). I'd requested the version shipped with Ubuntu but unfortunately it was not possible to obtain it, and hence I received a model shipped with Windows.
Obviously the first thing I did in these circumstances upon receiving the laptop was to install Ubuntu (24.04.1 LTS) on it.  Unfortunately Lenovo does not provide a custom image for this model, so I downloaded a standard image and installed it from the boot menu (I had to disable SecureBoot in the process, & now if I try to activate it it throws an error).
Using the laptop now, everything seems to work as intended, with one exception: the integrated pen.  On using it nothing happens; some web sites have suggested that I need to pair it with Bluetooth, but long-pressing the pen buttons seems to achieve nothing.  I've been staring at this problem for two hours — I've tried getting drivers for the pen, but all those on the Lenovo site are for Windows only.
How do I get this pen to work?
Bonus points if the answer also provides the right drivers for WWAN connections.

Edit: running xinput gave a list of devices with very obscure names (e.g. wayland-tablet stylus:15) but I worked out that libinput is much more informative:
$ sudo libinput list-devices

Device:           Wacom HID 5350 Pen
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             286x179mm
Capabilities:     tablet 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Disable-w-trackpointing: n/a
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a

(There are many more devices, but this seems to be the relevant one.) Why is everything marked “n/a” and how do I enable everything?

Information from comments:

I've managed to find the product page for the pen here, which says that it's AES1.0 protocol supported Windows 11. I hope that helps.


Further clarification: on pressing the pen buttons, no light turns on — I don't know whether it's supposed to or not. If an LED is supposed to turn on then my problem is actually the pen not charging…


I've been trying different things:

Tried updating UEFI BIOS with fwupdmgr update
Tried installing Lenovo Software Bridge using wine, but can't open the program (I'm not sure I've done it correctly)
Tried the solution described in this answer, namely sudo rmmod i2c_hid_acpi && sudo modprobe i2c_hid_acpi, to no discernible effect

None have been successful so far. Any ideas? I'm desperate.

Edit: interestingly enough, the Lenovo Vendor Software packaged with Linux doesn't seem to detect a pen/stylus (if I'm reading this right).  The output of fwupdmgr get-devices is:
LENOVO 21F2004YIX
│
├─ELAN06C4:00 04F3:3209:
│     Device ID:          afc91a0997faed7498298bff64beb6c319edd308
│     Summary:            Touchpad
│     Current version:    0x0004
│     Bootloader Version: 0x0003
│     Vendor:             ELAN Microelectronics (HIDRAW:0x04F3)
│     GUIDs:              38897f13-3a41-5b8a-9cc8-9370a2b41291 ← HIDRAW\VEN_04F3&DEV_3209
│                         4b69bffd-d456-54ae-baee-e11b517fa3bd ← HIDRAW\VEN_04F3&DEV_3209&MOD_0037
│                         3313b7ba-c61b-5183-a9c4-3411cc892998 ← ELANTP\ICTYPE_14&MOD_0037
│                         a97baf40-d178-5cf6-81e6-874542d698e2 ← ELANTP\ICTYPE_14&MOD_0037&DRIVER_HID
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│   
├─13th Gen Intel Core™ i5-1335U:
│     Device ID:          4bde70ba4e39b28f9eab1628f9dd6e6244c03027
│     Current version:    0x00004121
│     Vendor:             Intel
│     GUIDs:              c3f97ae6-7da2-54cc-ad26-3225f9517203 ← CPUID\PRO_0&FAM_06&MOD_BA
│                         cd7d026a-65a8-597d-a73f-b856af9dc9e2 ← CPUID\PRO_0&FAM_06&MOD_BA&STP_3
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│   
├─Embedded Controller:
│     Device ID:          1d6eecbfeb932a6d354f8d26bf0bd31735fe495e
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    0.1.12
│     Minimum Version:    0.1.12
│     Vendor:             Lenovo (DMI:LENOVO)
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               19d70a4e-b881-4e3d-8d58-4e6900b78fa8
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Supported on remote server
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─Fingerprint Sensor:
│     Device ID:          0d5d05911800242bb1f35287012cdcbd9b381148
│     Summary:            Match-On-Chip fingerprint sensor
│     Current version:    01000332
│     Vendor:             Goodix (USB:0x27C6)
│     Install Duration:   10 seconds
│     Serial Number:      UIDD884D92E_XXXX_MOC_B0
│     GUID:               14450e82-8667-54c3-98e1-098d8c6dc3b8 ← USB\VID_27C6&PID_6594
│     Device Flags:       • Updatable
│                         • Device can recover flash failures
│                         • Signed Payload
│   
├─Integrated Camera:
│     Device ID:          3fa281ddf80d8a06b8ee5d8beb48d38ee95a9627
│     Current version:    10.11
│     Vendor:              (USB:0x174F)
│     Serial Number:      200901010001
│     GUID:               ad04ffe9-9390-53f6-b9c7-6633dd6ab464 ← USB\VID_174F&PID_11A8
│     Device Flags:       • Updatable
│   
├─Intel Management Engine:
│     Device ID:          e48dfe46d6db1c20cba194830cafef4758d334e3
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1.25.2124
│     Vendor:             Lenovo (DMI:LENOVO)
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               0f552bed-f4b1-4a73-b6f3-1733002033ac
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]:
│     Device ID:          5792b48846ce271fab11c4a545f7a3df0d36e00a
│     Current version:    04
│     Vendor:             Intel Corporation (PCI:0x8086)
│     GUIDs:              7114c807-404e-558e-89a4-120d80d7cbdb ← PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A7A1
│                         d3af7562-10fd-5b41-bcc9-98e862417dfe ← PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A7A1&SUBSYS_17AA230C
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│   
├─SKHynix HFS512GEJ9X164N:
│     Device ID:          04e17fcf7d3de91da49a163ffe4907855c3648be
│     Summary:            NVM Express solid state drive
│     Current version:    51770C30
│     Vendor:             SK hynix (NVME:0x1C5C)
│     Serial Number:      4YC5N00741310554R
│     GUIDs:              c9f187c3-638d-5ee2-a4b0-c2e0cacd1a45 ← NVME\VEN_1C5C&DEV_1D59
│                         ed9f1364-2e23-5543-9538-57c8f805b281 ← NVME\VEN_1C5C&DEV_1D59&SUBSYS_1C5C1D59
│                         e16e9d50-aebe-5d52-b732-3ed9f80acb89 ← SKHynix_HFS512GEJ9X164N
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│                         • Signed Payload
│   
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          6c0e529a8dfc3048d1ea389db761e997cbd32eb2
│ │   Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│ │   Current version:    0.1.16
│ │   Vendor:             Lenovo (DMI:LENOVO)
│ │   Update State:       Success
│ │   GUID:               37a47c4a-af75-4b13-901e-0590565207d7
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │   Device Requests:    • Message
│ │ 
│ ├─BootGuard Configuration:
│ │     Device ID:        b0d4430dfa6bde9f0c22680df36dbc8c15c80753
│ │     Current version:  01
│ │     Vendor:           Intel Corporation (MEI:0x8086)
│ │     GUIDs:            dd17041c-09ea-4b17-a271-5b989867ec65
│ │                       fccad2fe-62ae-5879-b7a9-4ead7bce50f4 ← MEI\VEN_8086&DEV_51E0
│ │                       a62a3376-3af5-5a77-aa9e-676f28c8e08d ← MEI\VEN_8086&DEV_51E0&SUBSYS_17AA230C
│ │     Device Flags:     • Internal device
│ │   
│ └─UEFI dbx:
│       Device ID:        362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
│       Summary:          UEFI revocation database
│       Current version:  371
│       Minimum Version:  371
│       Vendor:           UEFI:Linux Foundation
│       Install Duration: 1 second
│       GUIDs:            5971a208-da00-5fce-b5f5-1234342f9cf7 ← UEFI\CRT_A9087D1044AD18F7A94916D284CBC01827CF23CD8F60B79072C9CAA1FEF4D649&ARCH_X64
│                         f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503&ARCH_X64
│       Device Flags:     • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • Supported on remote server
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│                         • Only version upgrades are allowed
│                         • Signed Payload
│     
├─TPM:
│     Device ID:          c6a80ac3a22083423992a3cb15018989f37834d6
│     Current version:    1.769.0.0
│     Vendor:             ST Microelectronics (TPM:STM)
│     GUIDs:              3680fbf1-593f-586f-91ac-c528b37e8373 ← TPM\VEN_STM&DEV_0000
│                         df479455-9790-58c9-b22a-bce5bc9eb149 ← TPM\VEN_STM&MOD_ST33TPHF2XSPI
│                         8d0b4adc-a42f-59eb-9df8-665923afa086 ← TPM\VEN_STM&DEV_0000&VER_2.0
│                         d565c809-9cf5-51c1-9ab7-d66b9d70ffbd ← TPM\VEN_STM&MOD_ST33TPHF2XSPI&VER_2.0
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device can recover flash failures
│                         • Full disk encryption secrets may be invalidated when updating
│                         • Signed Payload
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          81568164782039dbd4a74856cacb9800f408d44e
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    70159
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               4e88068b-41b2-4e05-893c-db0b43f7d348
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          7dccda75b1f76a97e675b08e7e0f8ab9924ad9ce
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               69585d92-b50a-4ad7-b265-2eb1ae066574
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          d049b1eed389189971d67479a222be053542ef11
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    18417740
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               897b03fb-1450-4000-b3f7-b2a6a4c13934
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          831a7cf58583415c8c7f1262cf07c45399687dda
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    16842756
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               3a6b1897-8621-4ea5-a3cc-00e743844642
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          3b44350411a36b454222dfe024764d5605c8c8b8
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1409421807
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               9a3acdcf-09d2-4cc1-bd28-0583a61f77c0
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          b73b43a0cbfee6364f5304f553a2264c7917bffa
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               39dab4fd-2b95-4432-b15b-5ed43ef55134
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          905705bf695f0904389bd167d9f4f3d80b8148e1
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    66305
│     Minimum Version:    66305
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               0910d662-7519-4648-9f4a-2a3d07ff2fb0
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          f905a7bd8805851b14be474d006372f37cc9342d
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               76ca0ad8-4a14-4389-b7e5-fd88791762ad
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          7e6427fb78fdb31553c3589b14cf9a40bd2e1f2e
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               626d93db-2c42-48c3-915a-71f968a81b04
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          bc43b8b6bfed153fbd83d2367db17d1d4d5a7ead
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    4113
│     Minimum Version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               e8b5bb2a-bf7e-46c2-b533-a48133f2cd13
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          6e006c24e6bd59e44572989e5eb0e03160b0def3
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    131072
│     Minimum Version:    57374
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               959e23c6-e124-4e7d-a120-93749e66b1ca
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          403cf5e7bd3a227ed00a9d00875cdcf81a56eb08
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    1
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               41e18891-fb01-4da3-a483-5b05ccbb5767
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   
├─UEFI Device Firmware:
│     Device ID:          fdd84657335a987615311c6bd2a42a0caf2b56be
│     Summary:            UEFI System Resource Table device (updated via NVRAM)
│     Current version:    4
│     Vendor:             DMI:LENOVO
│     Update State:       Success
│     GUID:               5b551832-e8cf-415f-9c5f-5a18c7ffa6e8
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│                         • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│     Device Requests:    • Message
│   


Can you confirm if the pen is a bluetooth pen or a Wacom-style pen (that gets activated when close to the screen)? Does the pen work in Windows when bluetooth is turned off?

Bonus points if the answer also provides the right drivers for WWAN connections. - Did you mean, wifi is not working?

I don't know how to verify whether the pen is Bluetooth or not.  I've gotten rid of Windows so can't use that as verification.  Is there any test I can do?

Regarding WWAN: this is about using the SIM slot that is present on the computer.

@ArchismanPanigrahi I've managed to find the product page for the pen here, which says that it's AES1.0 protocol supported Windows 11. I hope that helps.

Further clarification: on pressing the pen buttons, no light turns on — I don't know whether it's supposed to or not.  If an LED is supposed to turn on then my problem is actually the pen not charging…

It turns out that there is no software problem — it was hardware all along.
The issue was linked to the pen not charging, because of a misalignment of the charging pins inside the laptop. Once charged, the pen worked ‘out of the box’.
